# How to have date comparison in Scala LocalDateTime?

Tags: scala, datetime

I have datetime string in the format of `2019-07-21T00:00`. And also I get the current datetime using:

```
from_date = "2019-07-21T00:00"

// 2020-02-10T16:40:53.146
LocalDateTime.now().toString
```

**What I want to do** is to check whether given date-time is bigger than current date-time. **How can I** compare the above two date-times?

Comment: Have you tried https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#isAfter(java.time.chrono.ChronoLocalDateTime) ?

Comment: @mfirry I have used it like `myModel.from_date.get.isAfter(LocalDate.now)` but it gives and error of `TypeMismatch` complaining about `ChronoLocalDateTime`!

Comment: You can use DateTimeFormatter to format String to Date

Comment: `from_date` is a String. You first need to parse it into a `LocalDateTime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try parsing it first and then comparing it using the built-in methonds in `LocalDateTime`

Something along these lines:

```
LocalDateTime.parse(from_date).isAfter(LocalDateTime.now)
```